# Как отобразить в pdfMake , jsBarcode?

Tags: javascript

```
let dd = {
  render: function (data) {
    //что написать?
    return {
      content: [{
        svg: '//что написать?',
        width: 70
      }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render: function (data) {
function textToBase64Barcode(text){
           var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
           JsBarcode(canvas, text, {format: "CODE39"});
           return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
return {
   content: [
            {
                image: textToBase64Barcode(data.documentId),
                fit: [100, 100]
            },
}
```